# Debugging Git LFS - why isn't my pack file shrinking after git lfs import?

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

I have a UnrealEngine project with a bunch of uasset and umap files that I've tracked with LFS and not getting the results I expect.  The repository is a single pack file thats about 21gb. the working copy is about 25gb for a total of 46gb for the whole folder.

Have done the following with a new copy of the repo:

1. git lfs install
2. git lfs track "*.uasset"
3. git lfs track "*.umap"
4. git lfs migrate import --include="*.uasset,*.umap" --verbose --everything

This results in a ton of files being migrated based on what I'm seeing. Once its done I did:

1. git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
2. git gc --prune=now --aggressive

After running this I'm expecting the pack file to be a lot smaller but already know its not going to be because the gc takes forever, which means its re-compressing a ton of stuff. When its all said and done the pack file hasnt really changed size at all which is not what i'm expecting. I also now have a 20-something GB LFS folder.

Am I missing something? Not understanding how migrate is supposed to work? The usasset files are the majority of the space used in this repo.